# Uninitialized constant Stripe error when pushing to Heroku, but works locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

I have read a bunch of other threads similar to this, and have tried many of the suggestions to no avail. My app is running fine locally, but when I pushed to heroku after adding Stripe, it broke. Upon running `heroku run rails console heroku` I see I have an `uninitialized constant Stripe (NameError)` which is odd, since I have stripe in my gemfile (which seems to be one of the suggested fixes), have run bundle install numerous times, and it is working locally, even **more odd** is when I list my gems, I do not see it(Stripe). How can that be when I go to my Stripe dashboard, I can see my test transactions? Yet when I push to heroku, it is uninitialized....where do I start?

here is my gem list:

```
    $ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.3, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.8)
actionpack (4.2.3, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.8)
actionview (4.2.3, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.8)
activejob (4.2.3, 4.2.1, 4.2.0)
activemodel (4.2.3, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.8)
activerecord (4.2.3, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.8)
activesupport (4.2.3, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.8)
addressable (2.3.8)
arel (6.0.3, 6.0.2, 6.0.0, 5.0.1.20140414130214)
awesome_print (1.6.1)
backbars (0.0.11)
backports (3.6.4)
bcrypt (3.1.10)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
best_in_place (3.0.3)
better_errors (2.1.1)
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
buftok (0.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.6, 1.10.3)
byebug (6.0.0, 5.0.0, 3.5.1)
callsite (0.0.11)
coderay (1.1.0)
coffee-rails (4.1.0, 4.0.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1, 2.3.0)
coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1, 1.8.0)
columnize (0.9.0)
commonjs (0.2.7)
daemons (1.1.9)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
domain_name (0.5.24)
dotenv (2.0.2)
dotenv-rails (2.0.2)
equalizer (0.0.11)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.4)
execjs (2.6.0, 2.5.2, 2.2.2)
faraday (0.9.1)
ffaker (2.1.0, 2.0.0)
font-awesome-less (4.0.2)
foundation-rails (5.5.0.0)
git-version-bump (0.15.1)
github_api (0.12.3)
globalid (0.3.6, 0.3.5, 0.3.0)
handlebars (0.7.0)
handlebars-source (3.0.3)
handlebars_assets (0.20.2)
hashie (3.4.2)
hike (1.2.3)
http (0.6.4)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
httparty (0.13.5)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
jbuilder (2.3.1, 2.2.16, 2.2.6)
jquery-rails (4.0.4, 4.0.3, 3.1.3)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.2, 1.8.1)
jwt (1.5.0)
less (2.6.0)
less-rails (2.7.0)
libv8 (3.16.14.11 x86_64-darwin-14, 3.16.14.7 x86_64-darwin-14)
loofah (2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1)
mail (2.6.3)
memoizable (0.4.2)
meta_request (0.3.4)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (2.6.1, 2.4.3)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.8.0, 5.7.0, 5.5.1, 4.7.5)
multi_json (1.11.2, 1.11.1, 1.11.0, 1.10.1)
multi_xml (0.5.5)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
naught (1.0.0)
netrc (0.10.3)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2, 1.6.5)
oauth2 (1.0.0)
pg (0.18.2, 0.18.1)
pry (0.10.1)
pry-rails (0.3.4)
psych (2.0.5)
quiet_assets (1.1.0)
rack (1.6.4, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.5.5)
rack-contrib (1.4.0)
rack-protection (1.5.3)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.3, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.8)
rails-assets-backbone (1.2.1)
rails-assets-underscore (1.8.3)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7, 1.0.6, 1.0.5)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2, 1.0.1)
rails_12factor (0.0.3)
rails_layout (1.0.24)
rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.3)
rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
railties (4.2.3, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.8)
rainbow (2.0.0)
rake (10.4.2, 10.1.0)
rdoc (4.2.0, 4.1.0)
ref (2.0.0, 1.0.5)
rest-client (1.8.0, 1.6.7)
sass (3.4.16, 3.4.14, 3.3.14, 3.2.19)
sass-rails (5.0.3, 5.0.1, 4.0.5)
sdoc (0.4.1)
select2-rails (3.5.9.3)
simple_form (3.1.0)
simple_oauth (0.3.1)
sinatra (1.4.6)
sinatra-contrib (1.4.2)
slop (3.6.0)
spring (1.3.6, 1.2.0)
sprockets (3.3.1, 3.2.0, 2.12.4, 2.12.3)
sprockets-rails (3.0.0.beta1, 2.3.2, 2.3.1, 2.2.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.10)
test-unit (2.1.2.0)
therubyracer (0.12.2)
thin (1.6.3)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5, 0.3.4)
tilt (2.0.1, 1.4.1)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
twitter (5.14.0)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
uglifier (2.7.1, 2.7.0)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
unirest (1.1.2)
web-console (2.2.1, 2.1.2, 2.0.0)
```

Comment: What does the line in your `Gemfile` look like?

Comment: Do you see `stripe` in your `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: I just figured it out, I had the gem in the development part of the gemfile o_o

Comment: I have been through so much drama over this in the past day and a half, and as soon as I ask on SO, I have an epiphany. Lol. Thanks for jumping in to try to help :)

Comment: No problem. Sometimes what it takes is explaining the problem to someone else. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 0):

Solution:I had the gem in the development part of my gemfile